# How can I play Supreme Commander: Forged Alliance online?

Tags: supreme-commander

Are there any open networks or players that still play this game on non-official servers? I'm not able to get to the GPG-network from my Linux system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! Supreme Commander lives on here: [Forged Alliance Forever](http://www.faforever.com/)

There is a community created match making service, balance patches, mods, maps, etc.

If anyone can help you with getting Linux to connect, its the guys that read that support forum.

Comment: To add to your answer, you should note that GPG.NET is dead now.